# Testing REST routes with curl -X PUT, returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, express, mean-stack

I'm learning about the MEAN stack and am following the MEAN tutorial over at thinkster.io
https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/

I'm on the "Opening REST Routes" section. I'm trying to PUT an upvote using curl with the command:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/55387047f2334d2
c227e8079/upvote
```

I get the following error messages:

```
C:\Users\Michael\Desktop>curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/posts/55387047f2334d2
c227e8079/upvote
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<h2>404</h2>
<pre>Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\app.js:
39:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\n
ode_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:302:13)
    at C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node
_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:261:10)
    at C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:603:15
    at next (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:246:14)
    at Function.proto.handle (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules
\express\lib\router\index.js:166:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\ro
uter\index.js:35:12)</pre>
```

My mongoose schema is defined about the module.exports=app in app.js so I'm not sure what else to do. I checked my copy and pasting skills and there isn't a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the node server solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Did you double check that you did the previous step? Without a set router the page won't resolve.

```
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

That's the only thing I could think of could be the problems if you haven't had issues up until this step. Also you might check that your server can resolve via localhost, sometimes you have to use your private ip, 192.168, etc, because it depends on the network config your host has.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did the previous step. Everything was fine, including the creation of a post using curl. What do you mean check that your server can resolve via localhost? I am using curl and have not yet run anything on localhost. Should I? I'll go further ahead in the tutorial then.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing you're on a mac and everything is installed locally. I'm not a Mac expert, so I don't know if I could help you troubleshoot a mac-specific host/dns routing issue, but I doubt that's the case.

So based on the tutorial you just got mongoose configurated and you're running mongo. What happens when you run run 'mongo' command in terminal? Everything is good here right?

Comment: You're main app homepage is loading properly, correct? What do you get when you run 'curl http://localhost:3000/posts'

Comment: I'm running on Windows. Mongo works and puts me in the Mongo Shell.

Curl localhost:3000/posts works and gives me a bunch of posts with the ID's.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have an answer. I have spoken with several people who have gotten caught on this particular portion of the tutorial.

Under Opening REST Routes > Pre-Loading Objects, we are instructed to enter the following code:

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});
```

However, some people are consistently leaving out the second line:

```
var query = Post.findById(id);
```

or even interpolating it into the third line:

```
var query.exec(function(err, post) {
```

This may be the very simple solution to your problem.